# Cannot use different ssh key to access Git service

Tags: git, ssh

I use three ssh key to access to GitHub, GitLab and BitBucket. But I don't know why I only could access to GitLab. I use `ssh -T` to test. GitHub and Bitbucket all show up this `git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)`. I am sure I have add key to these services.

Here is the config at my .ssh folder.
Please help me.

```
# --- Sourcetree Generated ---
Host Rukeith-GitHub
    HostName github.com
    User Rukeith
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile /Users/rukeith/.ssh/Rukeith-GitHub
    UseKeychain yes
    AddKeysToAgent yes
# ----------------------------

# --- Sourcetree Generated ---
Host Rukeith-Bitbucket
    HostName bitbucket.org
    User Rukeith
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile /Users/rukeith/.ssh/Rukeith-Bitbucket
    UseKeychain yes
    AddKeysToAgent yes
# ----------------------------

# GitLab.com server
Host gitlab.com
    HostName gitlab.com
    User Rukeith
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile /Users/rukeith/.ssh/Rukeith-Gitlab
    UseKeychain yes
    AddKeysToAgent yes

# Private GitLab server
Host gitlab.company.com
    HostName gitlab.company.com
    User Rukeith
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile /Users/rukeith/.ssh/Rukeith-Gitlab
    UseKeychain yes
    AddKeysToAgent yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution is to use `ssh-add -K key` by myself.
A little problem.